# How to get input value by hovering on associated label

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following scenario:

```
<input class="rating__input" id="f21327c-4" value="4">
<label class="rating__label" for="f21327c-4"></label>
<input class="rating__input" id="f21327c-3" value="3">
<label class="rating__label" for="f21327c-3"></label>
<input class="rating__input" id="f21327c-2" value="2">
<label class="rating__label" for="f21327c-2"></label>
<input class="rating__input" id="f21327c-1" value="1">
<label class="rating__label" for="f21327c-1"></label>
...
```

How can I get the input's value by hovering on the related/associated label?

```
jQuery(".rating__label").hover(
function(){
   console.log("input value='' ");
  }
},
function(){
    console.log("unhovered");
}
);
```

Comment: you could use jquery.prev() method to get the current label's previous input field. https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/traversing_prev.asp or get the id and find input by id as in @richard-mclain answer

Answer (score 0):

since the label has the for= attribute with the id of the associated input - it is as simple as getting the attribute on the hover - and the finding the input with that id and getting its value.

You also do not need jQuery to achieve this... I have left it in - but added a querySelector() to demonstrate that too...

**NOTE That the label MUST have text in order to hover over it and return the result**

```js
jQuery(".rating__label").mouseover(
  function(){
    const id = this.getAttribute('for');
    const input = document.querySelector('#' + id);
    const value = input.value;
    console.log(value);
  }
)
```

```css
label, input{
display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="rating__label" for="f21327c-4">Input 1</label>
<input class="rating__input" id="f21327c-4" value="4"/>

<label class="rating__label" for="f21327c-3">Input 2</label>
<input class="rating__input" id="f21327c-3" value="3"/>

<label class="rating__label" for="f21327c-2">Input 3</label>
<input class="rating__input" id="f21327c-2" value="2"/>

<label class="rating__label" for="f21327c-1">inout 4</label>
<input class="rating__input" id="f21327c-1" value="1"/>
```